# How to access button in an item template of an asp.net "gridview" using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am relatively a new programmer. I have a gridview in which a button is repeated with every row.This button is an item template. When user clicks that button, another textbox colums value should be changed using javascript. This is what i tried. Everything is going perfect. When i click my button in a row of a grid, then the text of the textbox of that row is changed but suddenly disappears. It looks like as it is posting back. how to stop this??

OnclientClick ="myFunct(this)"

```
function myFunc(x){
   var id=x.id;
   var newID = id.substring(0, 18);
   newID+="TextBox1";
   document.getElementById(newID).value="ghjhghjg";
}
```

Regards

Comment: Show your full code and tell people what have you tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. Simply i need to return false onClientclick that would prevent it from postBack.

```
function myFunc(x){
var id=x.id;
var newID = id.substring(0, 18);
newID+="TextBox1";
document.getElementById(newID).value="ghjhghjg";
return false;
}
```

onclientClick="return myFunc()"

ThATS IT

Answer (score -1):

Try this with jquery

`$('#' + mygridview + ' input[id$=btnInput]').live("click",function () { });`

Many Thanks
Anna

Comment: why down vote...since i answered for "how to access button in an item template of an asp-net gridview"